# How to sort mutliple array value search in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an array of values that I want to search and display its contents. What is the best method to sort the array and show the result in the array's current format.

Example my array value

```
$myarray=array('84790','19162002','74739','86439','88820','19560020','19634461','19624154','19624091','19577228');

{
   "query":{
      "filtered":{
         "filter":{
            "bool":{
               "should":[
                  {
                     "term":{
                        "podcast_id":"84790"
                     }
                  },
                  {
                     "term":{
                        "podcast_id":"19162002"
                     }
                  },
                  {
                     "term":{
                        "podcast_id":"74739"
                     }
                  },
                  {
                     "term":{
                        "podcast_id":"86439"
                     }
                  },
                  {
                     "term":{
                        "podcast_id":"88820"
                     }
                  },
                  {
                     "term":{
                        "podcast_id":"19560020"
                     }
                  },
                  {
                     "term":{
                        "podcast_id":"19634461"
                     }
                  },
                  {
                     "term":{
                        "podcast_id":"19624154"
                     }
                  },
                  {
                     "term":{
                        "podcast_id":"19624091"
                     }
                  },
                  {
                     "term":{
                        "podcast_id":"19577228"
                     }
                  }
               ]
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

I am using php, curl and post method.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Terms filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.7/query-dsl-terms-filter.html) insted.

somthing like this :

```
{
"query": {
    "filtered": {

       "filter": {
           "terms": {
              "podcast_id": [
                 "84790",
                 "19162002",
                 .....
              ]
           }
       }
    }
  }
}
```